# Cannot isolate JDBC memory leak in Scala bulk data loading application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, scala, jdbc

I had written a sensor network webservice in Scala (it's my first Scala app; yes I know it uses Spring Dependency Injection. I'm in the process of ripping a lot of that out. Don't judge). Anyway, the company that was sponsoring it went under and I extracted all the data from the web service in its original XML data packages. I'm trying to load that data back into a database. The service supports Postgres, MySQL and Microsoft SQL (the original DB we used). I can get Postgres to load fine, but MySQL/Microsoft bombs out constantly with OutOfMemeory problems, even if I use an 8GB or 12GB heap.

I'm thinking the Postgres drivers may just be more efficient at internal data structures as I see the memory when using Postgres increase and not get released, just not as much. I'm careful to close ResultSet objects and Connection objects, but I'm still missing something.

Here is my Scala bulk loader that takes a tar.bz2 of XML files and loads it in

```
val BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
val PACKAGE_CHUNK_SIZE = 10000

def main(args : Array[String])  {

if(args.length != 1) {
  System.err.println("Usage: %s [bzip2 file]".format(this.getClass))
  System.exit(1)
}

val loader = MySpring.getObject("FormatAGRA.XML").asInstanceOf[FormatTrait]
val db     = MySpring.getObject("serviceDataHandler").asInstanceOf[ServiceDataHandlerTrait]

val bzin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new BZip2CompressorInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(args(0)))))
val models = new ListBuffer[ModelTrait]()
var chunks = 0

Stream.continually(bzin.getNextEntry()).takeWhile(_ != null) foreach {
  entry => {
    if(entry.asInstanceOf[TarArchiveEntry].isFile()) {

      val xmlfile = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      IOUtils.copy(bzin,xmlfile)
      //val models = new ListBuffer[ModelTrait]()
      models.appendAll( loader.loadModels(new String(xmlfile.toByteArray())) )
      System.out.println(String.format("Processing Entry %s",entry.getName));

      chunks = chunks + 1
      if( chunks % PACKAGE_CHUNK_SIZE == 0) {
        System.out.println("Sending batch of %d to database".format(PACKAGE_CHUNK_SIZE))
        db.loadData(models.toList.asInstanceOf[List[DataModel]])
        models.clear()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and now for those pesky Spring details. Here are my beans

```
<bean id="serviceDataHandler" parent="baseDataHandler" class="io.bigsense.db.ServiceDataHandler">
    <property name="ds" ref="serviceDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Database configurations -->
<bean id="baseDataSource" abstract="true" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
   <property name="driverClass" value="dbDriver" />
   <property name="jdbcUrl" value="connectionString" />
   <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60"/>
   <property name="idleMaxAge" value="240"/>
   <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="dbPoolMaxPerPart"/>
   <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="dbPoolMinPerPart"/>
   <property name="partitionCount" value="dbPoolPartitions"/>
   <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
   <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="100"/>
   <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3"/>
</bean>

<bean id="serviceDataSource" parent="baseDataSource" >
   <property name="username" value="dbUser"/>
   <property name="password" value="dbPass"/>
</bean>
```

Things like dbUser/dbPass/connectionString/dbDriver get replaced at compile time (later versions will use a runtime property file instead so you don't have to recompile the war for different configurations. But you get the basic idea.

The model that is pulled in as FormatAGRA.XML just reads the XML into an object (yea I know it's bad...XML is going away in the next release, JSON only!):

```
class AgraDataXMLFormat extends FormatTrait {

def renderModels(model : List[ModelTrait]) : String = {

if(model.length > 0) {
  model.head match {
    case x:DataModel => {
      return <AgraData>{ 
          for( pack <- model.asInstanceOf[List[DataModel]]) yield {
            <package id={pack.uniqueId} timestamp={pack.timestamp}>
            <sensors>{
              for( sensor <- pack.sensors) yield {
                <sensor id={sensor.uniqueId} type={sensor.stype} units={sensor.units} timestamp={sensor.timestamp}>
                <data>{sensor.data}</data></sensor>
              }
            }</sensors><errors>{ for(error <- pack.errors) yield {
              <error>{error}</error>
            }}
            </errors></package>
          }
      }</AgraData>.toString()       
    }
    case x:RelayModel => {
      return <AgraRelays>{ 
          for( r <- model.asInstanceOf[List[RelayModel]]) yield {
            /* TODO Get this working */
            /* <relay id={r.id} identifier={r.identifier} publicKey={r.publicKey} />*/
          }
      }</AgraRelays>.toString()
    }
    case _ => {
      //TODO: This needs to be an exception to generate a 400 BAD RESPONSE
      "Format not implemented for given model Type"
    }
  }
}
//TODO throw exception? No...hmm
""
}


def loadModels(data : String) : List[ModelTrait] = { 

var xml : Elem = XML.loadString(data)

var log : Logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())

var models = new ListBuffer[DataModel]

for( pack <- xml \\ "package") yield {

    var model = new DataModel()

    var sensors = pack \ "sensors"
    var errors = pack \ "errors"
    model.timestamp = (pack \"@timestamp").text.trim()
    model.uniqueId = (pack \"@id"  ).text.trim()

    var sbList = new ListBuffer[SensorModel]()
    var sbErr = new ListBuffer[String]()

    for( node <- sensors \"sensor") yield {
      var sensorData = new SensorModel()
      sensorData.uniqueId = (node\"@id").text.trim()
      sensorData.stype = (node\"@type").text.trim()
      sensorData.units = (node\"@units").text.trim()
      sensorData.timestamp  = (node\"@timestamp").text.trim()
      sensorData.data = (node\"data").text.trim()
      sbList += sensorData
    }
    for( err <- errors \"error") yield {
      model.errors.append(err.text.trim())
    }
    model.sensors = sbList.toList
    models += model
} 
models.toList
}

}
```

and finally the fun part. The Database stuff. There is a base trait. It has some boiler-plate stuff for closing connections and running queries. All queries use this runQuery(). I'm closing the connection and the result set. I can't quite figure out where the leak is. I have a feeling it has to do with the way I'm dealing with JDBC because, even though the leak exists in PostgreSQL (I can watch the memory increase in usage) it still completes the load without running out on an 8GB heap. The same data set fails around 100,000 records on MS SQL and MySQL

```
trait DataHandlerTrait {

@BeanProperty
var ds : DataSource = _

@BeanProperty
var converters : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,ConverterTrait] = _

@BeanProperty
var sqlCommands : EProperties = _

@BeanProperty
var dbDialect : String = _

val DB_MSSQL = "mssql"
val DB_MYSQL = "mysql"
val DB_PGSQL = "pgsql"

protected var log = Logger.getLogger(getClass())

//Taken From: http://zcox.wordpress.com/2009/08/17/simple-jdbc-queries-in-scala/
protected def using[Closeable <: {def close(): Unit}, B](closeable: Closeable)(getB: Closeable => B): B =
try {
  getB(closeable)
} finally {
  try { closeable.close() } catch { case e:Exception => {} }
}


protected def runQuery(req: DBRequest): DBResult = {

val retval = new DBResult()

val consBuilder = new StringBuilder(sqlCommands.getProperty(req.queryName))

val paramList: ListBuffer[Any] = new ListBuffer()
paramList.appendAll(req.args)

//constraints
// (we can't use mkstring because we need to deal with the
//  complex case of if something is an actual constraint (happens in query)
//  or a conversation (happens row by row)
var whereAnd = " WHERE "
for ((para, list) <- req.constraints) {
  val con = sqlCommands.getProperty("constraint" + para)
  if ((!converters.contains(para)) && (con == null || con == "")) {
    throw new DatabaseException("Unknown Constraint: %s".format(para))
  }
  else if (!converters.contains(para)) {
    for (l <- list) {
      consBuilder.append(whereAnd)
      consBuilder.append(con)
      paramList.append(l)
      whereAnd = " AND "
    }
  }
}
```

...and finally, the actual data load function:

```
def loadData(sets : List[DataModel]) : List[Int] = {

val log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())
var generatedIds : ListBuffer[Int] = new ListBuffer()


using(ds.getConnection()) { conn =>
    //Start Transaction
    conn.setAutoCommit(false)
    try{
        var req : DBRequest = null

        sets.foreach( set => {
          req = new DBRequest(conn,"getRelayId")
          req.args = List(set.uniqueId)
          val rid : DBResult = runQuery(req)

          var relayId : java.lang.Integer = null
          if(rid.results.length == 0) {
            req = new DBRequest(conn,"registerRelay")
            req.args = List(set.uniqueId)
            relayId = runQuery(req).generatedKeys(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
          }
          else {
            relayId = rid.results(0)("id").toString().toInt;
          }

          req = new DBRequest(conn,"addDataPackage")


          req.args = List(TimeHelper.timestampToDate(set.timestamp),relayId)
          val packageId = runQuery(req)
             .generatedKeys(0)
             .asInstanceOf[Int]
          generatedIds += packageId //We will pull data in GET via packageId      

          var sensorId : java.lang.Integer = -1
          set.sensors.foreach( sensor => {
             req = new DBRequest(conn,"getSensorRecord")
             req.args = List(relayId,sensor.uniqueId)
             val sid : DBResult = runQuery(req)
             if(sid.results.length == 0) {
               req = new DBRequest(conn,"addSensorRecord")
               req.args = List(sensor.uniqueId,relayId,sensor.stype,sensor.units)
               sensorId = runQuery(req).generatedKeys(0).toString().toInt
             }
             else {
               sensorId = sid.results(0)("id").toString().toInt;
             }
             req = new DBRequest(conn,"addSensorData")
             req.args = List(packageId,sensorId,sensor.data)
             runQuery(req)
          })
          set.processed.foreach( pro => {
            pro.units match {
              case "NImageU" => {
                req = new DBRequest(conn,"addImage")
                req.args = List(packageId, sensorId, new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(pro.data)))
                runQuery(req)
              }
              case "NCounterU" => { /*TODO: Implement Me*/}
              case _ => { set.errors.append("Unknown Processed Unit Type %s for Sensor %s With Data %s at Time %s"
                  .format(pro.units,pro.uniqueId,pro.data,pro.timestamp)) }
            }
          })          
          set.errors.foreach( error => {
            req = new DBRequest(conn,"addError")
            req.args = List(packageId,error)
            runQuery(req)
          })

        })
        conn.commit()
    }
    catch {
      case e:Exception => { 
        //make sure we unlock the transaction but pass the exception onward
        conn.rollback() 
        throw e
      }
    }
    conn.setAutoCommit(true)
    generatedIds.toList
}
}

//group by and order by
for (i <- List(req.group, req.order)) yield {
  i match {
    case Some(i: String) => consBuilder.append(sqlCommands.getProperty(i))
    case None => {}
  }
}

//prepare statement
log.debug("SQL Statement: %s".format(consBuilder.toString()))

/* PostgreSQL drivers quirk. If you use RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS, it adds RETURING
   to the end of every statement! Meanwhile, certain MySQL SELECT statements need RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS.
 */
var keys = Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
if (dbDialect == DB_PGSQL) {
  keys = if (consBuilder.toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("INSERT")) Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS else Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS
}

using(req.conn.prepareStatement(consBuilder.toString(), keys)) {
  stmt =>

  //row limit
    if (req.maxRows > 0) {
      stmt.setMaxRows(req.maxRows)
    }

    var x = 1
    paramList.foreach(a => {
      log.debug("Parameter %s: %s".format(x, a))
      a.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] match {
        case s: java.lang.Integer => {
          stmt.setInt(x, s)
        }
        case s: String => {
          stmt.setString(x, s)
        }
        case s: Date => {
          stmt.setDate(x, s, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")))
        }
        case s: Time => {
          stmt.setTime(x, s)
        }
        case s: Timestamp => {
          stmt.setTimestamp(x, s, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")))
        }
        case s: ByteArrayInputStream => {
          stmt.setBinaryStream(x, s, s.asInstanceOf[ByteArrayInputStream].available())
        }
        case s => {
          stmt.setObject(x, s)
        }
      }
      x += 1
    })


    //run statement
    stmt.execute()
    log.debug("Statement Executed")

    //get auto-insert keys
    val keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()
    if (keys != null) {
      var keybuf = new ListBuffer[Any]();
      while (keys.next()) {
        keybuf += keys.getInt(1)
      }
      retval.generatedKeys = keybuf.toList
    }

    //pull results
    log.debug("Pulling Results")
    using(stmt.getResultSet()) {
      ret =>
        if (ret != null) {

          val meta = ret.getMetaData()

          var retbuf = new ListBuffer[Map[String, Any]]()
          while (ret.next) {
            val rMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Any]()

            for (i <- 1 to meta.getColumnCount()) {
              rMap += (meta.getColumnLabel(i) -> ret.getObject(i))
            }

            //conversion
            for ((para, arg) <- req.constraints) {
              if (converters.contains(para)) {
                for (a <- arg) {
                  log.debug("Running Converstion %s=%s".format(para, a))
                  converters(para).convertRow(rMap, a.toString)
                }
              }
            }


            retbuf += Map(rMap.toSeq: _*)
          }

          retval.results = retbuf.toList
          ret.close()
        }
    }
    log.debug("Result Pull Complete")
}
retval
}


}
```

I've tried pumping it through monitors and looking at heap dumps and am not sure where to even being tackling this problem. I know I could split the bzip into smaller batches, but if there is a memory leak, I really need to start it. I don't want to have to restart cluster members every month or so in production.

Here is the commit with the current copy of the source code I'm working off of:

https://github.com/sumdog/BigSense/tree/fbd026124e09785bfecc834af6932b9952945fc6

Comment: In your position I'd be looking at heap usage with VisualVM, Eclipse Memory Analysis Tool, or jhat. I'm not sure there's any other reasonable way to d oit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue. After running everything through VisualVM, I noticed the thread count stayed constant, but there were a ton of JDBC4ResultSet objects sticking around. I thought I was closing all of them, but then I looked carefully and noticed this:

```
//get auto-insert keys
val keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys()
if (keys != null) {
  var keybuf = new ListBuffer[Any]();
  while (keys.next()) {
    keybuf += keys.getInt(1)
  }
  retval.generatedKeys = keybuf.toList
}
```

I didn't realize stmt.getGeneratedKeys() actually returns a ResultSet! Changing it to use the Closable wrapper fixed the issue:

```
    //get auto-insert keys
    using(stmt.getGeneratedKeys()) { keys =>
      if (keys != null) {
        var keybuf = new ListBuffer[Any]();
        while (keys.next()) {
          keybuf += keys.getInt(1)
        }
        retval.generatedKeys = keybuf.toList
      }
    }
```

Before:

[image: Memory profile of leak]

[image: Leaking ResultSet Objects]

and After:

[image: Memory usage after leak fix!]

Answer (score 0):

You posted a lot of information here.  My first pass on a memory leak is to make sure I'm closing all my old input and output streams (while I doubt they are the problem are you closing TarInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream?).  After making sure all that is sane I would check to see what files the process has open.  In Linux I would get the process ID and and do "ls /proc/${processID}/fd" and you can see all the files the process has open.  Finally get in visualvm or another profiler and see what's going on with the number of open Threads... if they continually increase over time you definitely have a memory leak from un-closed connections.  If there is no difference in the number of Threads between your process when using Postgres and the "others" then maybe you can conclude that the problem is the "others".  You idea of splitting up your input file could in theory solve the issue of the "others" if they are just have trouble handling that size of input at one time.